# How do I get an SQL Database in "Mirrored, Disconnected / In Recovery" into service?

Tags: sql-server, disaster-recovery, database-mirroring

I have an SQL Server 2005 mirrored database, with just the primary and secondary servers, no witness.  Tonight the primary has gone down and will not be back on-line for some time yet.  The secondary server is still running, but is "Mirrored, Disconnected / In Recovery".  How can I get the database back up and running?  My applications are all using a string that specifies the primary and secondary servers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe if you are not using a witness you can still enable the mirrored instance by using Forced Service. This method should pass the services on to your mirror but there is a risk of data loss. [This technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189977.aspx) should be able to start telling you the involved processes as well as the risks involved.

The T-SQL to force the mirror to take over is:

ALTER DATABASE database_name SET PARTNER FORCE_SERVICE_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS

With database_name being the name of the mirrored database. This must be run on the mirrored server.

Make sure you read the article before doing this so you know of any potential risks going in.

Answer (score 0):

Issue:- 
Mirrored databases are disconnected after restart of SQL instance due to 
Server Hang , 
You end the process of the SQL Server secondary instance by using Task Manager
Network Issue 
in SQL Server 2005 and above.

http://dbacentrals.blogspot.com/2017/07/mirrored-databases-are-disconnected.html